# TS - Variable 'x' is used before being assigned. TS(2454)

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is what I have, which returns no-redeclare warnings

```js
    if (sym === "BTCUSD") {
      var LastPrice = tickers[0].last_price;
      var LastDir = tickers[0].last_tick_direction;
      var High24 = tickers[0].high_price_24h;
      var Low24 = tickers[0].low_price_24h;
    }
    if (sym === "ETHUSD") {
      var LastPrice = tickers[1].last_price;
      var LastDir = tickers[1].last_tick_direction;
      var High24 = tickers[1].high_price_24h;
      var Low24 = tickers[1].low_price_24h;
    }
    if (sym === "EOSUSD") {
      var LastPrice = tickers[2].last_price;
      var LastDir = tickers[2].last_tick_direction;
      var High24 = tickers[2].high_price_24h;
      var Low24 = tickers[2].low_price_24h;
    }
    if (sym === "XRPUSD") {
      var LastPrice = tickers[3].last_price;
      var LastDir = tickers[3].last_tick_direction;
      var High24 = tickers[3].high_price_24h;
      var Low24 = tickers[3].low_price_24h;
    }
```

This is what I'm trying to write out..

```js
    if (sym === "BTCUSD") {
      var x = 0;
    }

    if (sym === "ETHUSD") {
      var x = 1;
    }

    if (sym === "EOSUSD") {
      var x = 2;
    }

    if (sym === "XRPUSD") { 
      var x = 3;
    }

    var LastPrice = tickers[x].last_price;
    var LastDir = tickers[x].last_tick_direction;
    var High24 = tickers[x].high_price_24h;
    var Low24 = tickers[x].low_price_24h;
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to clean this up and avoid any warnings and errors.

Edit: declaring var x = 0 prior does fix the error but it still leaves me with 4 warnings for re-declaring x instead of 12 for the others. is there a better way to write this?

Comment: Put `var x = null;` or `= 0` or something before all the ifs.

Comment: Create an enum instead of the multiple if blocks.

Comment: Which actually given your logic, there is an edge case where `sym` matches nothing, in which case `x` would be undefined for the array access.  `== problem`

Comment: declare variable once and assign inside if statements

Comment: `['BTCUSD', 'ETHUSD', 'EOSUSD', 'XRPUSD'].indexOf(sym)` would give the same results, ignoring the introduction of a `-1` result.

Comment: "_declaring var x = 0 prior does fix the error but it still leaves me with 4 warnings_". You should only declare a variable once within a scope. If you declare the variable above the if's, you should remove the `var` keyword within the if's. (When you are using TypeScript, you should stay away from `var` keyword anyway and use `let`/`const` instead.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an enum looking like this:

```
enum SymType {
  "BTCUSD",
  "ETHUSD",
  "EOSUSD",
  "XRPUSD"
}
```

Then use it like this instead of multiple if checks:

```
const {last_price, last_tick_direction, high_price_24h, low_price_24h} = tickers[SymType[sym]];
```

Comment: This is certainly the answer I needed, thank you. Never used enums before but this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

> TS - Variable 'x' is used before being assigned. TS(2454)

Reason: There is no guarantee that for the compiler that one of the `if`s will match ensuring that x gets assigned.

## Fix

One solution is to use an if else chain with an final else:

```
if (sym === "BTCUSD") {
  var x = 0;
}

else if (sym === "ETHUSD") {
  var x = 1;
}

else if (sym === "EOSUSD") {
  var x = 2;
}

else if (sym === "XRPUSD") { 
  var x = 3;
}

else { throw new Error('sym is not valid'); }

var LastPrice = tickers[x].last_price;
var LastDir = tickers[x].last_tick_direction;
var High24 = tickers[x].high_price_24h;
var Low24 = tickers[x].low_price_24h;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write, if I stick to your style

```
var symsObj = {
    "BTCUSD": 0,
    "ETHUSD": 1,
    "EOSUSD": 2,
    "XRPUSD": 3,
};

var x = symsObj[sym];

var LastPrice = tickers[x].last_price;
var LastDir = tickers[x].last_tick_direction;
var High24 = tickers[x].high_price_24h;
var Low24 = tickers[x].low_price_24h;
```